# How to show bootstrap-5 modals position dynamically on its trigger, for each trigger

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-5

How to show bootstrap-5 modals position dynamically? I am trying to create a Google calendar clone, suppose.. when we have more events on 28th and if we click on 4 more as shown in the below image then that modal should be open on the Wed 28th to its dedicated box, not in the center or any other place.
[image][DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/crazy-pond-518qc?file=/index.html)

Comment: You mean to say that the modal should be opened inside the 28th boundary box? Not above 1st or 6th, etc?

Comment: yes, like if you click on 20th then modal should appear on 20th

Comment: Okay got it. You need to do [Popovers](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/popovers/) in that case.

Comment: actually, I tried to but don't know how to use this in javascript, bcoz I want to many things which are not possible in normal Popover if we use a popover template using js then it works, I u know how to use popovers in Javascript can u tell me? https://v5.getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/popovers/#options

Comment: Checking the DEMO.

Comment: Add `position: relative` to `.days div` and remove `overflow: hidden` and for `.modal-sm` give `position: absolute; top: 0; display: block; left: 0px;`. I am able to make it work till this: https://i.imgur.com/D86eoXZ.png

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman , bro I think u not got my point [google calendar](https://calendar.google.com/calendar/u/0/r?tab=rc)   here if u go to that link and added -5 events then u will get more option just below the events in the date box ... and if u try for different dates same thing then u will get modal./popup on a dedicated date box, that is what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modals are not positioned relative to the trigger element, but Popovers (and Tooltips) are. Here's an example using Popovers...

Add the Popover in the markup for cells with events...

```
   <tr>
           <td>24</td>
           <td><div class="badge bg-info" 
                    data-bs-toggle="popover" 
                    data-bs-placement="bottom" 
                    data-bs-html="true"
                    >25</div>
           </td>
           <td>26</td>
           <td>27</td>
           <td>28</td>
           <td>29</td>
           <td>30</td>
   </tr>
```

Include the details in a hidden DOM element, or create the element dynamically in JS...

```
   <div class="d-none">
        <div id="dailyEventsContent">
            <div class="rounded p-1 my-1 bg-info small text-white">8:00 event 1</div>
            <div class="rounded p-1 my-1 bg-info small text-white">8:40 event 2</div>
            <div class="rounded p-1 my-1 bg-info small text-white">9:30 event 3</div>
            <div class="rounded p-1 my-1 bg-info small text-white">10:00 event 4</div>
            <div class="rounded p-1 my-1 bg-info small text-white">3:00 event 5</div>
        </div>
   </div>
```

Enable Popovers and set the `content` option

```
var popoverContent = document.getElementById('dailyEventsContent')
var popoverTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle="popover"]'))
var popoverList = popoverTriggerList.map(function (popoverTriggerEl) {
  return new bootstrap.Popover(popoverTriggerEl, {
      content: popoverContent
  })
})
```

https://codeply.com/p/AKvIsoHJOl